# Create more than one type of arrays of PictureBox

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I'm trying to create more than one array of PictureBox.
The only thing I know is that I can use limited amount of arrays that was created in a code.

```vb
Dim CustomImage() As PictureBox = New PictureBox() {Array1, Array2,..and so on}
```

But what I'm trying to explain is how do you create those arrays something like this?
In this example, the user inputs number 6 and it shows 6 PictureBoxes.

```vb
Dim ArrayNumber as Integer = 6

Dim CustomImage() As PictureBox = New PictureBox() {some code that creates 6 arrays}
```

Comment: "Array1" is a very odd name for a picturebox control.  The odds that this code can work correctly are low, you must pass variables that were initialized.  In Sub New, after the InitializeComponent() call is the earliest.

Comment: How do I do that, I'm confused at this point?

Comment: @MohamedHussain Are you saying that `Array1`, `Array2`, and so on are arrays of PictureBoxes, so that you want an array of arrays of PictureBoxes?

Comment: do you want store images or Picture Box Controls?

Answer (score 0):

Just sample:

```
Dim myPictBox As PictureBox()
Private Const maxPBCount = 10

Private Sub CreateSomePictureBox(ByVal Count As Int16)
    If Count > maxPBCount Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim myPictBoxLength As Integer = 0
    If myPictBox Is Nothing = False Then
        myPictBoxLength = myPictBox.Length
    End If

    Do While myPictBoxLength > Count
        myPictBox(myPictBoxLength - 1).Dispose()
        myPictBoxLength -= 1
    Loop
    If Count <= 0 Then
        myPictBox = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ReDim Preserve myPictBox(Count - 1)
    'Arrange Position of PictureBox
    MsgBox(myPictBoxLength)
    Do While myPictBoxLength < Count
        myPictBox(myPictBoxLength) = New PictureBox
        myPictBox(myPictBoxLength).Height = 30 
        myPictBox(myPictBoxLength).Width = 30
        myPictBox(myPictBoxLength).Location = New Point(35 * myPictBoxLength, 30)
        Me.Controls.Add(myPictBox(myPictBoxLength))
        myPictBox(myPictBoxLength).BackColor = Color.Red
        myPictBox(myPictBoxLength).Show()
        myPictBoxLength += 1
    Loop
    'Create Sub Procedure to Arrange The Picture Box Created 
    'ArrangePB()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
    CreateSomePictureBox(6)
End Sub
```

Comment: `myPictBoxLength = myPictBox.Length` The Length property is an Integer not an Int16.

Comment: What is `ArrangePB()`?

Comment: A `Size` in not a `.Location`.

Comment: ArrangePB is sub procedure to place picture box to container, may be I forget to copy, for above sample no need because have been assigned in creating.
MyPictBoxLength will be changed to integer. The location assign, I forget to changed, sorry...